# Django CSRF Token error or missing with Ajax POST request

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-csrf

I am trying to integrate ajax into a web application with the Django framework. I am however having a hard time trying to make a simple ajax call to work.

I want to make a DB connection using a form (where users input the DB credentials), call the API, then return the output (whether successful or not).

Here's my **views.py** that is used to handle the API:

```
# -- START from HERE !
class TestConnectionAPI(views.APIView):
    '''
    Test DB Connection from TARGET DB
    '''  
    def post(self, request):
        dbs = (request.data['host'],
                request.data['port'],
                request.data['dbname'],
                request.data['user'],
                request.data['password'],
                request.data['schema_name'])

        try:
            x = dc.DbConnection(*dbs)
            x.create_conn()
            data = x.check_conn()           
            
            result = {
                'message' : 'Success',
                'server' : f'Connection established from {data}',
                'results':{
                    'host':dbs[0],
                    'port':dbs[1],
                    'dbname':dbs[2]
                    },
            }
            return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except Exception as e:
            return Response({'Message':str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This is my **connection.html** to display the form (complete code: [here](https://gist.github.com/furanzone/7300c1c6a12fd0d561ccd0e30dfbf585)) :

```
...
<form method="post">
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="host">Hostname</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="host" name="host" aria-describedby="host">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="port">Port</label>
                                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="port" name="port" placeholder="e.g., 5432">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="database">Database name</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dbname" name="dbname" placeholder="Enter database name">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" name="user" placeholder="Enter username">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="schema">Schema</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="schema_name" name="schema_name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer border-top-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
                                        <a href="#form2" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Test</a>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
...
```

And, here's the **AJAX function** for calling the API (POST request):

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function () {

        let _host = $('#host').val();
        let _port = $('#port').val();
        let _dbname = $('#dbname').val();
        let _user = $('#user').val();
        let _password = $('#password').val();
        let _schema_name = $('#schema_name').val();

        var $crf_token = $('[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').attr('value');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            headers:{"X-CSRFToken": $crf_token},
            data:{
                "host" : _host,
                "port" : _port,
                "dbname" : _dbname,
                "user" : _user,
                "password" : _password,
                "schema_name": _schema_name,
            },

            url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err_msg = ''
                for (var prop in xhr.responseJSON) {
                    err_msg += prop + ': ' + xhr.responseJSON[prop] + '\n';
                }

                alert(err_msg);
                },
            
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

This is my **error**:
[image]

However, I have a hard time fixing the error. I tried to follow some discussion in the StackOverflow forum, but I still have this error. The error is related to **the CSRF token**, where it is difficult for me to follow the Django documentation.

At least I want to display this API response on the console log.

```
{
    "message": "Success",
    "server": "Connection established from ('PostgreSQL 12.7, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit',)",
    "results": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 5432,
        "dbname": "dvdrental"
    }
}
```

**Added-1**: POST request header
[image]

Could you please help me to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Check the POST request using the browser inspector. Does it send the correct value in `X-CSRFToken` header?

Comment: @Selcuk, Excuse me, thank you for your response. I checked using the browser inspector. Unfortunately, I cannot find the `X-CSRFToken`. Is this another problem also? I added the result to the question.

Comment: Looks like that's your issue. I see that some requests are going to `test` while others are for `test/`. Is there a redirect from one to the other? That might cause the browser to drop your header.

Comment: @Selcuk, Yes, there are redirect from one page to another page in my `views.py` file. However, I resolved my error by adding some functions (i.e., Cookies) to the AJAX script. Thankfully, I can see the `X-CSRF Token` header and fetch the data from API. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to fix my problem. I added some script to the main function. By using this script, my error message: csrf token invalid or missing is resolved.

**Edited** script:

```
<script>
    // DB Connection GET method
    function BindConnection(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test",
            
            success: function(data){
                console.log("BindConnection output:",data);
                
                var str = "";

                for (var key in data){
                    // console.log(data[key]);
                    str += "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" + data[key] + "</td>"
                    "</tr>"
                }
                $("#divBody").html(str);
            }
        });
    }

    // DB Connection POST method
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {

        let _host = $('#host').val();
        let _port = $('#port').val();
        let _dbname = $('#dbname').val();
        let _user = $('#user').val();
        let _password = $('#password').val();
        let _schema_name = $('#schema_name').val();

        // added function
        function Cookies(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }

        var csrftoken = Cookies('csrftoken');
        
        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }

        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });
        // --- end of added function

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data:{
                "host" : _host,
                "port" : _port,
                "dbname" : _dbname,
                "user" : _user,
                "password" : _password,
                "schema_name": _schema_name,
            },
            url:"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/test/",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err_msg = ''
                
                for (var prop in xhr.responseJSON) {
                    err_msg += prop + ': ' + xhr.responseJSON[prop] + '\n';
                }

                // alert(err_msg);
                $("#divMessage").html(err_msg)
                },
            
            success: function (result) {
                var str = "";
                
                for (var key in result){
                    str += "<p>" + result[key] + "</p>"
                }
                $("#divMessage").html(str)
                console.log(str)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```